# Expose custom endpoint to base-path in Spring Boot Data Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Boot Data Rest and I can list all endpoints using follling url:

```
http://localhost:8080/api
```

It lists following endpoints:

```
{
"_links": {
    "tacos": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/tacos{?page,size,sort}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "orders": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/orders"
    },
    "ingredients": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/ingredients"
    },
    "profile": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile"
    }
}
```

}

But I have a custom end point created like below in Controller

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class RecentTacosController {

private TacoRepository tacoRepo;

public RecentTacosController(TacoRepository tacoRepo) {
    this.tacoRepo = tacoRepo;
}

@GetMapping(path = "/tacos/recent", produces = "application/hal+json")
public ResponseEntity<Resources<TacoResource>> recentTacos() {

    PageRequest page = PageRequest.of(0, 12, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
    List<Taco> tacos = tacoRepo.findAll(page).getContent();
    List<TacoResource> tacoResources = new TacoResourceAssembler().toResources(tacos);
    Resources<TacoResource> recentResources = new Resources<TacoResource>(tacoResources);
    recentResources.add(ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn(RecentTacosController.class).recentTacos()).withRel("recents"));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(recentResources, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

But this endpoint (http://localhost:8080/api/tacos/recent) is not listed when doing GET on base path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement `ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource>` in one of your class (could be the controller itself), add the following method:

```
  @Override
  public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource resource) {
    resource.add( ... );
    return resource;
  }
```

... and create and add the proper link to your custom method there.